# Why does a TextBlock prevent the button event from firing?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015

After adding a `TextBlock` to maingrid the button event wont fire anymore

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    grid.Children.Add(new Line());
    grid.Children.Add(new TextBlock()); 
}

private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    button.Content = "OK"; 
}
```

```html
 <Grid x:Name="grid">
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="142,107,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="287" Click="button_Click" Height="114"/>
</Grid>
```

started a wpf project from the scratch (VS2015). Inserted a Button and this lines of code.
Without adding the TextBlock everything works fine!
(I reduced the code to the minimum, so no attributes are set)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Children of a grid share the same visual space unless they're given different rows/columnss. Most likely your textblock overlaps and covers your button. Try adding them to different columns or rows.

Comment: Reduced the size (width/height) - problem solve. Thx a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The `TextBlock` you added will cover the button as long as no alignment and/or size was specified for the `TextBlock`.

If there is no good reason to overlay the `TextBlock`, you might want to restructure your `Grid` layout.